# Google Maps API on Internet Explorer for Windows Phone

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3, windows-phone

I'm testing Google Maps Web API with Fusion Tables layer. It works great on Chrome, Firefox, IE 11 desktop. I'm facing some problems on IE 11 for Windows Phone 8.1.

The most important one is simple, but can make the product just unusable. When the map does not use 100% of the screen, it might freeze if your finger slide from the outside of the map to the inside !

I've uploaded [a test page here](http://samuel.levitt.fr/test1.html) with some further explanations. Feel free to read the source code (very basic).

Is it a known bug ? Is there a workaround ?